# angular directives ng-if replace: true

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I don't really know what happens here
take a look at this 
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bbNU8ziYBs8MDVVMLhh1)

the example doesn't work and only works with this template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/showErrors.html">
<div>           
    <div data-ng-if="errors">
        <p  class="alert alert-danger fade-in" data-ng-repeat="error in errors" data-ng-bind="error"></p>
    </div>
</div>          
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because when you have set `replace: true` an actual  directive div then it is div get replaced by template and its attribtes get merged

for example add class your to outer div of template

```
 <div class="yes" data-ng-if="errors">---------------------
                                                           |
                                                           | 
      and your directive div is  below                     > replaces and attributs are merged
                                                           |  
    <div show-errors errors="main.errors"></div> ----------
```

now when replace= true, resulting outer div after attributes get merged becomes

```
<div show-errors="" errors="main.errors" 
      class="yes ng-binding ng-scope" data-ng-if="errors">...</div>
```

so errors in ng-if is not available yet here in outer div when replace:true; and is available inside

trying with `replace: false` works fine. thats why you need extra div

Comment: I can follow you may be :) but I'm waiting like https://gist.github.com/whisher/87fec61f49c66de77e82 from ng-book so I just expect to see just div data-ng-if="errors"

Comment: thats not the complete code or example so that i can follow?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/hJSCmRUBGiLq7vF7fsPV now the behaviour is different from the book  with replace:true it's the first element of the template directive to get renoved .....

Comment: you have an spelling mistake in seconf extra 's' you wrote directives intead of directive..